# how to pick up string inside a <li> tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a simple list and a form text-field:

```
<ul>
  <li class="item">one</li>
  <li class="item">two</li>
  <li class="item">three</li>
  <li class="item">four</li>
</ul>
<input id="field" type="text" />
```

When the user clicks on an `<li>` item, I want the string inside the li element to be assigned the value of the input field.

Something like:

```
$('.item').click( function(){
  $('#field').val(/*put the string inside the li element just clicked*/);
});
```

So how do I get the string in the `li` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.item').click(function(){    
    $('#field').val($(this).html()); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally suggest using a very similar suggestion to those already-posted, but with `text()` rather than html:

```
$('.item').click(
    function(){    
        $('#field').val($(this).text());
    });
```

It's a slim justification, but, as the docs note:

> Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML documents.

Otherwise they seem to be much the same.

Reference:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/);

Answer (score 2):

`.html()` is what you're looking for. Please look it up in the API : http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
$('.item').click( function(){
  $('#field').val($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item').click( function(){
  $('#field').val($(this).html());
});
```